# Parse an GPO XML with R or Python

Tags: r, active-directory, xml-parsing, gpo

I need to parse a bunch of exported AD GPO XMLs to csv/xls or any other filetype with unpivoted data.
Generally, I need only GPO Name, GPO Description and whom affected by this policy.

So, I tried to make it by myself with R, but I had a problem with parsing itself.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GPO xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings">
  <Identifier>
    <Identifier xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">{0E8443B7-E547-4C6C-B201-A60D567795CF}</Identifier>
    <Domain xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">********</Domain>
  </Identifier>
  <Name>ITSEC Event Log Forward</Name>
  <IncludeComments>true</IncludeComments>
  <CreatedTime>2012-11-21T05:54:01</CreatedTime>
  <ModifiedTime>2020-09-02T09:05:31</ModifiedTime>
  <ReadTime>2022-03-01T14:52:26.625719Z</ReadTime>
  <SecurityDescriptor>
    <SDDL xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types/Security">O:S-1-5-21-;;S-1-5-21-)(OA;OICI;CR;edacfd8f-ffb3-11d1-b41d-00a0c968f939;;S-1-5-21-)(OA;OICI;CR;edacfd8f-ffb3-11d1-b41d-00a0c968f939;;AU)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOSDRCWDWO;;;S-1-5-21-)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOSDRCWDWO;;;S-1-5-21-685724207-866877060-2473498247-36290)(A;OICI;LCRPRC;;;S-1-5-21-685724207-866877060-2473498247-18511)(A;OICI;LCRPRC;;;S-1-5-21-685724207-866877060-2473498247-37622)(A;OICIIO;0x1f00ff;;;S-1-5-21-685724207-866877060-2473498247-18510)(A;OICIIO;0x11f00ff;;;S-1-5-21-685724207-866877060-2473498247-36290)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOSDRCWDWO;;;SY)(A;OICI;LCRPRC;;;ED)(A;OICI;LCRPRC;;;AU)(A;OICIIO;0x1f00ff;;;SY)S:AI(OU;CIIDSA;CCDC;f30e3bc2-9ff0-11d1-b603-0000f80367c1;;WD)(OU;CIIDSA;WPWD;;f30e3bc2-9ff0-11d1-b603-0000f80367c1;WD)(OU;CIIDSA;WPSD;;f30e3bc2-9ff0-11d1-b603-0000f80367c1;WD)(OU;CIIOIDSA;WP;f30e3bbe-9ff0-11d1-b603-0000f80367c1;bf967aa5-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2;WD)(OU;CIIOIDSA;WP;f30e3bbf-9ff0-11d1-b603-0000f80367c1;bf967aa5-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2;WD)(OU;CIIDSA;CR;9923a32a-3607-11d2-b9be-0000f87a36b2;;WD)(OU;CIIDSA;CR;bae50096-4752-11d1-9052-00c04fc2d4cf;;WD)(OU;CIIDSA;CR;440820ad-65b4-11d1-a3da-0000f875ae0d;;WD)(OU;CIIDSA;CCDC;bf967a86-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2;;WD)(OU;CIIDSA;CCDC;bf967a9c-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2;;WD)(OU;CIIDSA;CCDC;bf967aa5-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2;;WD)(OU;CIIDSA;CCDC;bf967aba-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2;;WD)(OU;CIIOIDSA;WPSD;;bf967a86-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2;WD)(OU;CIIOIDSA;WPSD;;bf967a9c-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2;WD)(OU;CIIOIDSA;WPSD;;bf967aa5-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2;WD)(OU;CIIOIDSA;WPSD;;bf967aba-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2;WD)(AU;CIIDSA;CCWPDTSDWDWO;;;WD)</SDDL>
    <Owner xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types/Security">
      <SID xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">S-1-5-21-</SID>
      <Name xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">AD\AGPMService</Name>
    </Owner>
    <Group xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types/Security">
      <SID xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">S-1-5-21-685724207-866877060-2473498247-512</SID>
      <Name xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">AD\Domain Admins</Name>
    </Group>
    <PermissionsPresent xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types/Security">true</PermissionsPresent>
    <Permissions xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types/Security">
      <InheritsFromParent>false</InheritsFromParent>
      <TrusteePermissions>
        <Trustee>
          <SID xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">S-1-5-21-</SID>
          <Name xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">AD\All users</Name>
        </Trustee>
        <Type xsi:type="PermissionType">
          <PermissionType>Allow</PermissionType>
        </Type>
        <Inherited>false</Inherited>
        <Applicability>
          <ToSelf>true</ToSelf>
          <ToDescendantObjects>true</ToDescendantObjects>
          <ToDescendantContainers>true</ToDescendantContainers>
          <ToDirectDescendantsOnly>false</ToDirectDescendantsOnly>
        </Applicability>
        <Standard>
          <GPOGroupedAccessEnum>Read</GPOGroupedAccessEnum>
        </Standard>
        <AccessMask>0</AccessMask>
      </TrusteePermissions>
      <TrusteePermissions>
        <Trustee>
          <SID xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">S-1-5-9</SID>
          <Name xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">NT AUTHORITY\ENTERPRISE DOMAIN CONTROLLERS</Name>
        </Trustee>
        <Type xsi:type="PermissionType">
          <PermissionType>Allow</PermissionType>
        </Type>
        <Inherited>false</Inherited>
        <Applicability>
          <ToSelf>true</ToSelf>
          <ToDescendantObjects>true</ToDescendantObjects>
          <ToDescendantContainers>true</ToDescendantContainers>
          <ToDirectDescendantsOnly>false</ToDirectDescendantsOnly>
        </Applicability>
        <Standard>
          <GPOGroupedAccessEnum>Read</GPOGroupedAccessEnum>
        </Standard>
        <AccessMask>0</AccessMask>
      </TrusteePermissions>
      <TrusteePermissions>
        <Trustee>
          <SID xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">S-1-5-11</SID>
          <Name xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users</Name>
        </Trustee>
        <Type xsi:type="PermissionType">
          <PermissionType>Allow</PermissionType>
        </Type>
        <Inherited>false</Inherited>
        <Applicability>
          <ToSelf>true</ToSelf>
          <ToDescendantObjects>true</ToDescendantObjects>
          <ToDescendantContainers>true</ToDescendantContainers>
          <ToDirectDescendantsOnly>false</ToDirectDescendantsOnly>
        </Applicability>
        <Standard>
          <GPOGroupedAccessEnum>Apply Group Policy</GPOGroupedAccessEnum>
        </Standard>
        <AccessMask>0</AccessMask>
      </TrusteePermissions>
      <TrusteePermissions>
        <Trustee>
          <SID xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">S-1-5-21-</SID>
          <Name xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">AD\AGPMowner</Name>
        </Trustee>
        <Type xsi:type="PermissionType">
          <PermissionType>Allow</PermissionType>
        </Type>
        <Inherited>false</Inherited>
        <Applicability>
          <ToSelf>true</ToSelf>
          <ToDescendantObjects>true</ToDescendantObjects>
          <ToDescendantContainers>true</ToDescendantContainers>
          <ToDirectDescendantsOnly>false</ToDirectDescendantsOnly>
        </Applicability>
        <Standard>
          <GPOGroupedAccessEnum>Apply Group Policy</GPOGroupedAccessEnum>
        </Standard>
        <AccessMask>0</AccessMask>
      </TrusteePermissions>
    </Permissions>
    <AuditingPresent xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types/Security">false</AuditingPresent>
  </SecurityDescriptor>
  <FilterDataAvailable>true</FilterDataAvailable>
  <Computer>
    <VersionDirectory>287</VersionDirectory>
    <VersionSysvol>287</VersionSysvol>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <ExtensionData>
      <Extension xmlns:q1="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/Windows/Registry" xsi:type="q1:RegistrySettings">
        <q1:RegistrySettings clsid="{A3CCFC41-DFDB-43a5-8D26-0FE8B954DA51}">
          <q1:Collection clsid="{53B533F5-224C-47e3-B01B-CA3B3F3FF4BF}" name="EventLogSubscription" status="Values generated by the Registry Wizard" changed="2013-04-24 06:23:32" uid="{E5A36FB5-C34A-4156-8EAF-7E8D243AB7EC}" bypassErrors="1">
            <q1:GPOSettingOrder>1</q1:GPOSettingOrder>
            <q1:Filters />
            <q1:Registry clsid="{9CD4B2F4-923D-47f5-A062-E897DD1DAD50}" name="EventLogSubscription for 000" descr="Wizard Generated Registry Item" image="7" status="1" changed="2015-11-06 07:59:00" uid="{009827A2-E767-418E-8C84-7250030565E8}" bypassErrors="1">
              <q1:GPOSettingOrder>1</q1:GPOSettingOrder>
              <q1:Properties action="U" displayDecimal="0" default="0" hive="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" key="SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EventLog\EventForwarding\SubscriptionManager" name="1" type="REG_SZ" value="Server=">
                <q1:Values />
              </q1:Properties>
              <q1:Filters>
                <q1:FilterCollection bool="AND" not="0">
                  <q1:FilterCollection bool="AND" not="0">
                    <q1:FilterComputer bool="AND" not="0" type="NETBIOS" name="00*" />
                    <q1:FilterComputer bool="OR" not="0" type="NETBIOS" name="01*" />
                  </q1:FilterCollection>
                </q1:FilterCollection>
              </q1:Filters>
            </q1:Registry>
            <q1:Registry clsid="{9CD4B2F4-923D-47f5-A062-E897DD1DAD50}" name="EventLogSubscription for 030" descr="Wizard Generated Registry Item" image="7" status="1" changed="2015-11-06 07:58:51" uid="{D1757DF9-B1D4-4646-8BC1-57A22C883EC4}" bypassErrors="1">
              <q1:GPOSettingOrder>2</q1:GPOSettingOrder>
              <q1:Properties action="U" displayDecimal="0" default="0" hive="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" key="SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EventLog\EventForwarding\SubscriptionManager" name="1" type="REG_SZ" value="Server=http://030">
                <q1:Values />
              </q1:Properties>
              <q1:Filters>
                <q1:FilterCollection bool="AND" not="0">
                  <q1:FilterComputer bool="AND" not="0" type="NETBIOS" name="03*" />
                </q1:FilterCollection>
              </q1:Filters>
            </q1:Registry>
            <q1:Registry clsid="{9CD4B2F4-923D-47f5-A062-E897DD1DAD50}" name="EventLogSubscription for 040" descr="Wizard Generated Registry Item" image="7" status="1" changed="2015-11-06 07:59:19" uid="{976CF190-22E6-43A6-9444-002F4B1E1BBA}" bypassErrors="1">
              <q1:GPOSettingOrder>3</q1:GPOSettingOrder>
              <q1:Properties action="U" displayDecimal="0" default="0" hive="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" key="SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EventLog\EventForwarding\SubscriptionManager" name="1" type="REG_SZ" value="Server=http://040">
                <q1:Values />
              </q1:Properties>
              <q1:Filters>
                <q1:FilterCollection bool="AND" not="0">
                  <q1:FilterComputer bool="AND" not="0" type="NETBIOS" name="04*" />
                </q1:FilterCollection>
              </q1:Filters>
            </q1:Registry>
            <q1:Registry clsid="{9CD4B2F4-923D-47f5-A062-E897DD1DAD50}" name="EventLogSubscription for 0600" descr="Wizard Generated Registry Item" image="7" status="1" changed="2015-11-06 07:59:34" uid="{1CC2A25B-30C6-42CD-BC86-2ED9B2E1A874}" bypassErrors="1">
              <q1:GPOSettingOrder>4</q1:GPOSettingOrder>
              <q1:Properties action="U" displayDecimal="0" default="0" hive="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" key="SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EventLog\EventForwarding\SubscriptionManager" name="1" type="REG_SZ" value="Server=http://060">
                <q1:Values />
              </q1:Properties>
              <q1:Filters>
                <q1:FilterCollection bool="AND" not="0">
                  <q1:FilterComputer bool="AND" not="0" type="NETBIOS" name="06*" />
                </q1:FilterCollection>
              </q1:Filters>
            </q1:Registry>
            <q1:Registry clsid="{9CD4B2F4-923D-47f5-A062-E897DD1DAD50}" name="EventLogSubscription for 070" descr="Wizard Generated Registry Item" image="7" status="1" changed="2015-11-06 07:59:48" uid="{8A3FCBF8-FD61-4ECB-AA91-DEB9C681682C}" bypassErrors="1">
              <q1:GPOSettingOrder>5</q1:GPOSettingOrder>
              <q1:Properties action="U" displayDecimal="0" default="0" hive="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" key="SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EventLog\EventForwarding\SubscriptionManager" name="1" type="REG_SZ" value="Server=http://070">
                <q1:Values />
              </q1:Properties>
              <q1:Filters>
                <q1:FilterCollection bool="AND" not="0">
                  <q1:FilterComputer bool="OR" not="0" type="NETBIOS" name="07*" />
                </q1:FilterCollection>
              </q1:Filters>
            </q1:Registry>
            <q1:Registry clsid="{9CD4B2F4-923D-47f5-A062-E897DD1DAD50}" name="EventLogSubscription for 090" descr="Wizard Generated Registry Item" image="7" status="1" changed="2015-11-06 08:00:15" uid="{08CF4699-0EE7-4761-8244-7B1901138BD5}" bypassErrors="1">
              <q1:GPOSettingOrder>6</q1:GPOSettingOrder>
              <q1:Properties action="U" displayDecimal="0" default="0" hive="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" key="SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EventLog\EventForwarding\SubscriptionManager" name="1" type="REG_SZ" value="Server=http://090">
                <q1:Values />
              </q1:Properties>
              <q1:Filters>
                <q1:FilterCollection bool="AND" not="0">
                  <q1:FilterComputer bool="AND" not="0" type="NETBIOS" name="09*" />
                </q1:FilterCollection>
              </q1:Filters>
            </q1:Registry>
            <q1:Registry clsid="{9CD4B2F4-923D-47f5-A062-E897DD1DAD50}" name="EventLogSubscription for 080" descr="Wizard Generated Registry Item" image="7" status="1" changed="2015-11-06 08:00:02" uid="{D2DE191A-43A9-476D-94FA-9C8F341C470A}" bypassErrors="1">
              <q1:GPOSettingOrder>7</q1:GPOSettingOrder>
              <q1:Properties action="U" displayDecimal="0" default="0" hive="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" key="SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EventLog\EventForwarding\SubscriptionManager" name="1" type="REG_SZ" value="Server=http://080">
                <q1:Values />
              </q1:Properties>
              <q1:Filters>
                <q1:FilterCollection bool="AND" not="0">
                  <q1:FilterComputer bool="AND" not="0" type="NETBIOS" name="08*" />
                </q1:FilterCollection>
              </q1:Filters>
            </q1:Registry>
          </q1:Collection>
        </q1:RegistrySettings>
      </Extension>
      <Name>Windows Registry</Name>
    </ExtensionData>
    <ExtensionData>
      <Extension xmlns:q2="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/Registry" xsi:type="q2:RegistrySettings">
        <q2:Policy>
          <q2:Name>Configure log access</q2:Name>
          <q2:State>Enabled</q2:State>
          <q2:Comment>INC000007330355</q2:Comment>
          <q2:Explain>This policy setting specifies the security descriptor to use for the log using the Security Descriptor Definition Language (SDDL) string. You cannot configure write permissions for this log. You must set both "configure log access" policy settings for this log in order to affect the both modern and legacy tools.

If you enable this policy setting, only those users whose security descriptor matches the configured specified value can access the log.

If you disable or do not configure this policy setting, only system software and administrators can read or clear this log.

Note: If you enable this policy setting, some tools and APIs may ignore it. The same change should be made to the "Configure log access (legacy)" policy setting to enforce this change across all tools and APIs.</q2:Explain>
          <q2:Supported>At least Windows Vista</q2:Supported>
          <q2:Category>Windows Components/Event Log Service/Security</q2:Category>
          <q2:EditText>
            <q2:Name>Log Access</q2:Name>
            <q2:State>Enabled</q2:State>
            <q2:Value>O:BAG:SYD:(A;;0xf0005;;;SY)(A;;0x5;;;BA)(A;;0x1;;;S-1-5-32-573)(A;;0x1;;;s-1-5-20)</q2:Value>
          </q2:EditText>
        </q2:Policy>
      </Extension>
      <Name>Registry</Name>
    </ExtensionData>
  </Computer>
  <User>
    <VersionDirectory>21</VersionDirectory>
    <VersionSysvol>21</VersionSysvol>
    <Enabled>false</Enabled>
  </User>
  <LinksTo>
    <SOMName>Domain Controllers</SOMName>
    <SOMPath>m/Domain Controllers</SOMPath>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <NoOverride>false</NoOverride>
  </LinksTo>
</GPO>
```

[image]

Thanks for helping such newbies as me.
Cheers!

Comment: Share your example data as text and not as an image so we can copy the data into our own environments

Comment: XML example added. Thanks!

Comment: The given XML is invalid. You can see this in the syntax highlighting of this post.

Comment: Sorry mate, I didn't catch you clearly. What do you mean?

Comment: `read_xml("data.xml", encoding = "UTF-16")` results into `Error in read_xml.character("data.xml", encoding = "UTF-16") : 
  Start tag expected, '<' not found [4]`

Comment: I don't know how to fix it. Maybe UTF-8 might work, 'cause there could be an cyrillic symbols

Comment: I've fixed the xml in the question and posted my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting the document to UTF-8 using `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` and fixing a missing `"` using `value="Server=http://080">`, one can extract XML nodes using XPath and convert them to a list and then to a data frame, so it can be saved as an CSV table:

```
library(xml2)
library(tidyverse)

xml <-
  read_xml("data.xml", encoding = "UTF-8") %>%
  xml_ns_strip() 

data <-
  xml %>%
  xml_find_all("//Name") %>%
  as_list() %>%
  enframe() %>%
  unnest_auto(value)
data
# name value                                        
# <int> <chr>                                        
#   1     1 "ITSEC Event Log Forward"                    
# 2     2 "AD\\AGPMService"                            
# 3     3 "AD\\Domain Admins"                          
# 4     4 "AD\\All users"                              
# 5     5 "NT AUTHORITY\\ENTERPRISE DOMAIN CONTROLLERS"
# 6     6 "NT AUTHORITY\\Authenticated Users"          
# 7     7 "AD\\AGPMowner"                              
# 8     8 "Windows Registry"                           
# 9     9 "Registry" 

data %>% write_csv("data.csv")

# extract a particular user id
xml %>%
  xml_find_all("//User/VersionSysvol") %>%
  xml_text() %>%
  as.numeric()
#[1] 21


xml %>%
  xml_find_all("//Trustee/Name") %>%
  xml_text()
# [1] "AD\\All users"  "NT AUTHORITY\\ENTERPRISE DOMAIN CONTROLLERS" "NT AUTHORITY\\Authenticated Users"
```